# ssh key is removed from (ssh-agent?) every few days

Tags: macos, ssh

I have two ssh key pairs, one for personal project and another for work.  I have an `~/.ssh/config` that looks like:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes

Host personalGH
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalKey

# Work GitHub
Host workgh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workKey

Host helper
    HostName helper.intranet.work.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/eng_rsa
    User eng
```

Every few days, or week, I will push some branch to my work repo and get an authentication failure.  (having read a few posts about ssh-agent, it seems likely that this corresponds to reboots).

So my questions are, `a)` why does my work key "get cleared" on these occasions, `b)` this doesn't seem to happen to my personal key, why is that?, `c)` how can I make the storing of my keys persistent between reboots (if that is indeed what is causing the loss of persistence).

I've read that storing keys in keychain is an option, but I don't really care for using passcodes.

As seen by the many qualifying parentheticals, not only am I having problems with ssh but I'm not even clear on what the problems are precisely.  So any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to your OS's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file? If so, why not copy your directives into it and see if they remain? I'm assuming something's overwriting your directives from the OS level, though that shouldn't be happening. I know MacOS uses OpenBSD's version of SSH, so perhaps something was updated recently, breaking your config.

Comment: Try adding `ssh-add -A &>/dev/null` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: whats the &>/dev/null do?